# Is absolutely necessary join in the domain to write in Active Directory from C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008

For now, i achieve read the users in a Organizational Unit.
But when i try edit an user property ( the email in this case), the exception show me a 'access denied'.
The machine which contains the Active Directory and my machine (which contains the app) are in the same Lan network, but my machine is not joined in the domain (it's a requirement).
So, i need read and write in Active Directory but the machine should not be joined in the domain, just do the login. This is possible? how?.

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.10.0.15/OU=OU_Users,DC=Sales,DC=local", "user123", "pass123"))
            {
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                SearchResult result;
                SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
                if (resultCol != null)
                {
                    for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
                    {
                        result = resultCol[counter];

                        if (result.Properties.Contains("mail"))
                        {                                
                            using (DirectoryEntry userToEdit = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
                            {

                                userToEdit.Properties["mail"].Clear();
                                userToEdit.Properties["mail"].Add("changedemail@gmail.com");
                                userToEdit.CommitChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: should be able to use an account like Domain Admin or an account that has domain access and use DOMAIN\User and password to do this. Your credentials should be valid, but it's not necessary that the PC be joined to the domain to do that.

Comment: Perhaps user123 doesn't actually have the permissions necessary to make the change?

Comment: Yes, finally i discovered that the user123´s group did not had permission to write.
Thanks!